# Connecting peers via USB OTG

Tags: usb, avr, usb-otg

my problem is to connect two identical devices with OTG-capable USB interfaces. Is this a simple giveaway or do I have to start and stop host- and device-mode manually with an arbitrary timing pattern so that eventually one is hit in device mode when the other one is an OTG host? From skimming over the APIs of several USB-stack producers it is unclear to me if symmetrical connections are possible at all.

regards,
slarti

PS: the device is an AVR32

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The official cable has a "jumper" in the A end that tells the device it is plugged into to be the host. The OTG Supplement also includes a Host Negotiation Protocol which allows the two dual-role devices to interchange roles.

Comment: A really good resource to learn more about OTG is: http://www.cypress.com/?docID=14347